# smart resource bundle editor for Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, add-on

is in Idea any smart resource bundle editor? Because the built-in one is useless, it can't create new strings, can't rename them, delete them or even search in them. When you have 5 .properties files, you have to edit them all to make a change. Is there some kind of addon or plugin which would serve as resource bundle editor and would be usefull at the same time? Eclipse has very good one for example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Resource Bundle editor (opened via the *Resource Bundle* tab at the bottom of a properties file) is primarily meant for **editing the values** of the keys. If you keep that in mind, its usage paradigm becomes a bit easier to understand. It would be nice if some added functionality were added to the "Resource Bundle" editor/tab. I recommend voting for and/or opening feature requests so it can be improved as there are no third party plug-ins available for resource bundles.

Here are some answers to your specific concerns.

> ...can't rename them...

You can rename. Open one of the bundles properties file. On the Text tab, put your cursor on the key and launch the rename refactoring (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> by default or in the Refactor menu). Enter the new name in the dialog box. This will rename it in all resource bundle files and anywhere it is used in code. You can also launch the rename with your cursor on the key when in code. I agree that its a small shortcoming that can't launch the rename for a key in the "resource bundle" tab of one of the properties files. You can only rename the bundle itself there. But again, that's because the philosophy is the "Resource Bundle" editor is for editing the values. Anything else is done in the properties file itself.

> ...can't ... delete them...

This is indeed a significant shortcoming. There is a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-36915) to add this functionality. (Please vote for it.) In the meantime, you can still make some use of the safe delete. In a resource bundle properties file, place your cursor on the key and launch "Safe Delete" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>). If there are any usages of the key still, IDEA will warn you. Unfortunately, once all uses are cleared, you will need to delete the key from all the bundles. But you can make use of the "Remove unused property" quick fix (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>↩</kbd>) in each properties file. Another option would be after running the safe delete to ensure all uses are removed, use *Analyze > Run Inspection by name* to run the "Unused Property" inspection. In the results window, right click the top level node and select "Remove Property" and it will be removed in all properties files. You could record a Macro (Edit > Macros) to make this more efficient.

> ...create new strings...

Again, an unfortunate shortcoming that you can't create a new key in the *Resource Bundle* tab and have it appear in all properties files. But as I mentioned, that tab/editor is meant for editing values, not keys. I *think* the logic behind this is that sometimes a key does not need to appear in the hierarchy of files. For example, if US and UK are the same, it only needs to be in `foo_en.properties` and not `foo_en_US` and `foo_us_UK`. So if a key was added, it would need to be added only where needed. I think the fix for that is there could be a setting for the default file where new keys are initially added. Then as you add values in the editor, the key is added to other files. Anyway, there is a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101056) for this. Please consider voting for it. In the meantime, what you can do is add the key via the "Text" tab in one properties file, then switch to the "Resource Bundle" tab, select the key and add the values for the other properties files. Yes, a bit of a hassle, but still workable I think.

> ...or even search in them...

This is possible. Place your cursor on the key either in its usage in code or in the "Text" tab of one of the properties files and use the "Find Usages" action (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> or *Edit > Find > Find Usages*). It will then show all the usages. Use "Find Usages Settings..." if needed.

Comment: thank you for your advices, I will vote for those requests. And I ment searching not usages, but strings (ctrl+F or live search in the tree).